# Performing Coreference Resolution on .mtx data file

Tags: python, spacy, coreference-resolution

I'm attempting to perform Coreference Resolution on this BBC dataset: http://mlg.ucd.ie/datasets/bbc.html

Using the Neuralcoref model seen here: https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref

However, having never worked with the .mtx file format, I'm stumped how I should pass the BBC data from the .mtx format to the spacy (and neuralcoref) pipeline.

I realize I have to use the *mmread* module to read the data, but how exactly would I pass the .mtx data to Spacy and Neuralcoref? Here's what I've done so far:

```
from scipy.io import mmread

# Specify the path to the .mtx file
file_path = "data/bbc.mtx"

# Read the .mtx file
matrix = mmread(file_path)

# Print the matrix
print(matrix)
```

Then, Neuralcoref's sample goes like this:

```
# Load your usual SpaCy model (one of SpaCy English models)
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# Add neural coref to SpaCy's pipe
import neuralcoref
neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp)

# You're done. You can now use NeuralCoref as you usually manipulate a SpaCy document annotations.
doc = nlp("My sister has a dog. She loves him.")

doc._.has_coref
doc._.coref_clusters
```

I tried simply passing the matrix variable as

```
doc = nlp(matrix)
```

but didn't get what I expected. Would really appreciate some help, as I feel I'm out of my depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this won't work because the matrix from the .mtx file is a sparse matrix and doesnt contain the text required for coreference resolution.

you are looking for something like this i think

```
import spacy
import neuralcoref

# Load SpaCy model
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# Add NeuralCoref to the pipeline
neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp)

# Preprocess and concatenate the BBC text data
# Replace this with your actual preprocessing code to extract the relevant text
bbc_text = "My sister has a dog. She loves him."

# Process the BBC text data
doc = nlp(bbc_text)

# Perform coreference resolution
clusters = doc._.coref_clusters

# Print the coreference clusters
for cluster in clusters:
    main_mention = cluster.main
    mentions = cluster.mentions
    print(f"Main mention: {main_mention.text}")
    print(f"Mentions: {[mention.text for mention in mentions]}")
    print()
```

Comment: I found a .csv version of the data and will be using that instead. If anyone else has this issue, there are .mtx to .csv converters that can be used, though I'm not sure how reliable they are. Thanks Alex!